# Get all count of stored procedures executed of database in last 24 hours

Tags: sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I want to know how many stored procedures and how much time executed for data fetching in last 24 hours in SQL Server?

Answer (score 1):

**How to Get the Execution Count of a Stored Procedure?**

To determine how many times a stored procedure in the cache has been executed you need to use a couple of DMV’s and a dynamic management function (DMF). The plan_handle for the cached plans are used to join together the DMV’s and retrieve records for a DMF. To get the execution counts for each cached SPs you can run the following code:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) SchemaName
      ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) StoredProcedure
      ,max(cp.usecounts) Execution_count
 FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp
         CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
 where DB_NAME(st.dbid) is not null and cp.objtype = 'proc'
   group by cp.plan_handle, DB_NAME(st.dbid),
            OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid), 
   OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
 order by max(cp.usecounts)
```

Here I used the plan_handle of the “sys.dm_exec_cached_plans” DMV to obtain the object type. I used the object type to identify stored procedure cached plans. The “usecounts” column of the “sys.dm_exec_cached_plans” DMV identifies the number of times each statement with a cached_plan (or SP) has been executed since the last compilation of the SP, I called this “Execution_count”. I use the plan_handle in conjunction with the CROSS APPLY operator to return the object information (DBName, SchemaName, and ObjectName) using the table-value DMF “sys.dm_exec_sql_text”. The output from this SELECT statement is ordered by the “Execution_count”, so the SP with the most executions will be displayed first.

**Determining Which SP is using the Most CPU, I/O, or has the Longest Duration.**

Knowing which SPs are frequently executed is useful information, although from a performance standpoint you might like to know which SP is consuming the greatest amount of CPU resources. Or possibly you might be interested in which SP takes the longest to run, or which SP performs the most physical I/O operations? By modifying the above command, we can easily answer each one of these questions.

If you want to show the SP that consumes the most CPU resources you can run the following TSQL command:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) SchemaName
      ,OBJECT_NAME(st.objectid,dbid) StoredProcedure
      ,max(cp.usecounts) Execution_count
      ,sum(qs.total_worker_time) total_cpu_time
      ,sum(qs.total_worker_time) / (max(cp.usecounts) * 1.0)  avg_cpu_time
 
 FROM sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp join sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs on cp.plan_handle = qs.plan_handle
      CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(cp.plan_handle) st
 where DB_NAME(st.dbid) is not null and cp.objtype = 'proc'
 group by DB_NAME(st.dbid),OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid), OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
 order by sum(qs.total_worker_time) desc
```

The “sys.dm_exec_query_stats” view contains the column “total_worker_time”, which is the total number of microseconds that a given cached query plan has executed. Keep in mind that cached plans are sometimes removed from memory and replaced with newer ones. Therefore, the statistics for which SP has consumed the most CPU only takes into account statistics for those plans that are in the cache when this T-SQL is run.

To determine which SP has executed the most I/O requests you can run the following TSQL code:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) SchemaName
      ,OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) StoredProcedure
      ,max(cp.usecounts) execution_count
      ,sum(qs.total_physical_reads + qs.total_logical_reads + qs.total_logical_writes) total_IO
      ,sum(qs.total_physical_reads + qs.total_logical_reads + qs.total_logical_writes) / (max(cp.usecounts)) avg_total_IO
      ,sum(qs.total_physical_reads) total_physical_reads
      ,sum(qs.total_physical_reads) / (max(cp.usecounts) * 1.0) avg_physical_read    
      ,sum(qs.total_logical_reads) total_logical_reads
      ,sum(qs.total_logical_reads) / (max(cp.usecounts) * 1.0) avg_logical_read  
      ,sum(qs.total_logical_writes) total_logical_writes
      ,sum(qs.total_logical_writes) / (max(cp.usecounts) * 1.0) avg_logical_writes  
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) st
   join sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp on qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
  where DB_NAME(st.dbid) is not null and cp.objtype = 'proc'
 group by DB_NAME(st.dbid),OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid), OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
 order by sum(qs.total_physical_reads + qs.total_logical_reads + qs.total_logical_writes) desc
```

Here I have displayed the total physical and logical read I/O’s, plus the logical write I/O’s. In addition, I have calculated the average number of I/O’s per execution of each SP. Physical reads are the number of reads that are actually made against the physical disk drives; where as logical reads and writes are the number of I/O’s against the cached data pages in memory in the buffer cache. Therefore, by adding the physical and logical I/O’s together I was able to calculate the total I/O’s for each SP.

To determine which SP’s take the longest time to execute I can use the follow TSQL code:

```
SELECT DB_NAME(st.dbid) DBName
      ,OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) SchemaName
      ,OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) StoredProcedure
      ,max(cp.usecounts) execution_count
      ,sum(qs.total_elapsed_time) total_elapsed_time
      ,sum(qs.total_elapsed_time) / max(cp.usecounts) avg_elapsed_time
 FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats qs CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.plan_handle) st
   join sys.dm_exec_cached_plans cp on qs.plan_handle = cp.plan_handle
  where DB_NAME(st.dbid) is not null and cp.objtype = 'proc'
 group by DB_NAME(st.dbid),OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(objectid,st.dbid), OBJECT_NAME(objectid,st.dbid) 
 order by sum(qs.total_elapsed_time) desc
```

In this TSQL, I am calculating the duration of each SP by summing up the “total_elapsed_time” in the “sys.dm_exec_sql_query_stats” DMV by database, schema and object name. I am also calculating the average elapsed time per execution of each SP. I order the output so the SP that took the longest total duration will be displayed first. If you where interested in determining the SP that had the longest average duration all you would need to change is the “ORDER BY” clause to sort by “avg_elapsed_time”.

[reference](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3687186/Monitoring-Stored-Procedure-Usage.htm)

Comment: Thanks @DV Singh but i need to know last 24 hours how many stored procedure and how many times called means I nedd to total calls of particular database in last 24 hours

Comment: if you get timestamp with that data then filter it out, maybe u can ready more docs about how make it time based